# What's the difference between loop unrolling and blocking in matrix multiply?

Tags: c

It seems like no difference for me, both of them are trying to reuse some data to reduce the access to memory.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is the 'gemm'?  Do you mean "blocking" as in "progress is blocked", or as in "grouping something into (memory?) blocks"?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about that, gemm is general matrix multiply, and blocking means divide the result matrix in subblocks to compute

Comment: Loop unrolling writes out some number of iterations of the loop as separate statements, thus saving on loop control variable testing, etc.  I think 'blocking' refers to trying to increase the locality of reference — which saves on memory cache misses, etc, and matters especially on big matrices.  But, I'm no expert on the topic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are making very sense, thank you anyway

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But increasing the locality of reference does also write out some number of iterations of the loop as separate statements. They might be for different purpose but on the implementation I really cannot see any difference.